# Java ClassCastException thrown when trying to iterate through the list

Tags: java, classcastexception

My code fails with a `ClassCastException` while running. I've tried to debug but in vain. I have declared a Class Subject with fields and am trying to load objects of that class into a list. Below is the code. It fails at the line: `List items = (List)(it.next())`. Adding `?` for generics does not help. I guess the object is cast, though there are no generics mentioned in the `List` declaration. Is there a basic concept that I'm missing here?

In the below method, I'm trying to encode the data into an xml file.

```
 private void encodeSection(PrintStream output, Indenter indenter,
                                   String name, List list) {
            String indent = indenter.makeString();

            output.println(indent + "<" + name + "s>");

            indenter.in();
            String indentNext = indenter.makeString();

            if (list == null) {
                // the match is any
                output.println(indentNext + "<Any" + name + "/>");
            } else {
                String nextIndent = indenter.makeString();

                Iterator it = list.iterator();
                indenter.in();

                while (it.hasNext()) {
                  List items = (List)(it.next());//-------------> Error occurs
                    output.println(indentNext + "<" + name + ">");

                    Iterator matchIterator = items.iterator();
                    while (matchIterator.hasNext()) {
                        TargetMatch tm = (TargetMatch)(matchIterator.next());
                        tm.encode(output, indenter);
                    }

                    output.println(indentNext + "</" + name + ">");
                }

                indenter.out();
            }

            indenter.out();
            output.println(indent + "</" + name + "s>");
        }

    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: SubjectID_V cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at Target_V.encodeSection(Target_V.java:71)
    at Target_V.encode(Target_V.java:41)
at com.sun.xacml.AbstractPolicy.encodeCommonElements(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xacml.PolicySet.encode(Unknown Source)
    at PolicyFactory_V.main(PolicyFactory_V.java:56)
```

Comment: You haven't posted your whole code. Also your erros are most likely because you are trying to casting one type of collection into other, which is probably not allowed. What is the type of your `SubjectID_V`?

Comment: You're using a lot of `raw types` here. Please look up what generic types are and how do you use them in `List` and `Iterator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List items = (List)(it.next())` will only work if the `List` you are iterating over contains just elements of type `List` (i.e. instances of classes implementing the `List` interface).

Based on the error you got, you are trying to cast an instance of type `SubjectID_V` to a `List`. You should look at the code that initializes that list. Your error might be there.

Using generic Lists may have helped you to avoid this exception, since it would have prevented the code from passing compilation in the first place.